# Sentiment Analysis Of A Dataset With Multiple NewsPaper Articles

Tags: r, sentiment-analysis, sentimentr

I'm trying to call ***get_nrc_sentiment*** in R but getting the following error:

> Error in get_nrc_sentiment(Test) : Data must be a character vector.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

```
library("RDSTK")
library("readr")
library("qdap")
library("syuzhet")
library("ggplot2")

library(readxl)
Test <- read_excel("Test.xlsx")
View(Test)

scores = get_nrc_sentiment(Test) //throwing error
```

Comment: Please include the contents of your Test.xlsx file or better yet rewrite your question without the Excel dependency.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please, add some data to make your code working, in this way you're going to have some quality answer. If you can, you should publish the output of `dput(head(test))` (use `head()` if your data are too much to be published) or create a dataset to copy and paste in R, that throws the error you want to fix.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the Test.xlsx file your are reading in has multiple columns. In that case, the Test object would not be a character vector, but a dataframe. Putting the dataframe object into the get_nrc_sentiment() causes the error. You can check test with class(Test) to determine what kind of R object it is.